# Excel data validation for decimals, but without a range?

Tags: microsoft-excel, data-validation

I want to use the Data Validation in Excel to prevent users from entering a non-decimal value, but I want to allow them to enter any decimal value, however you are forced to provide a range or restriction.  Is there way to force a decimal, but not have to put a restrictions on the range of values?

Comment: Can you make the range so large that it doesn't matter?

Comment: Kind of what I've done in the meanwhile.  I selected "Value not equal to" and put 999999999999.  Then the odds of it ever being exactly that value are pretty small I supposed, just feels a bit hackish.

Comment: this could be done with macros. if you're interested let me know and I'll throw together an example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try these:

#### Method 1: Checking for any number

- Highlight the cell you wish to apply validation to. For this example, let's assume you want the user to enter a value in **A1**.
- Go to  **Data** > **Data Validation**
- Set to **Custom**
- Enter the formula below.

  `=ISNUMBER(A1)`

where **A1** is the cell you are validating. Do not include $ so you can copy/paste the validation to other cells.

[image]

#### Method 2: Checking for decimal pts

Create a blank column beside your data. For this example, you want users to enter values in column A, so we'll create a blank column in B.

In cell B1, enter this formula and drag it down.

`=AND(ISNUMBER(A1), FIND(".",TEXT(A1,"#.#"))<>LEN(TEXT(A1,"#.#")))`

*Credits to DMA57361 for the tip*

- Highlight **A1**.
- Go to **Data** > **Validation**
- Set to **Custom** and enter the formula below:

  `=B1`
- Do **Copy** > **Paste Special** > **Validation** to other cells.

I'm sure there are other methods. This was all I could muster in a few mins.

Comment: +1, But note that you can greatly simplify your macro by letting the language do the string search for you with `If (InStr(num, ".") > 0) Then`.

Comment: Also, you could probably pull off the "check for a decimal point" approach with an ugly formula instead of having to go to the level of a macro, for example `=FIND(".",TEXT(A1,"#.#"))<>LEN(TEXT(A1,"#.#"))` seems to work.

Comment: @DMA57361 Thanks for the macro tip; I'll adjust the code. :D Also, I tried to do a formula for the Data Validation. Something along the lines of "=NOT(ISNA(FIND(".",A1)))" but for some reason I couldn't make it work.

Comment: @Hidden, `FIND` returns `#VALUE!` when it fails, not `#N/A`, so `ISNA()` won't help here. Note that just doing a `FIND` on the `.` character would mean "word.word" would be falsely accepted - you *have* to check it's a valid number as well (in fact, that's probably a flaw in the macro and my previous suggestion as well).

Comment: I added an ISNUMBER check. Problem is, Excel auto-converts "15.00" to "15" so whole numbers are ignored, even when the user types it in decimal form.

Comment: Whole numbers are fine.  Basically trying to prevent things that would fail to import into a database's decimal field.  15.54.45 would be bad for example.  So usually I select multiple fields, holding CTRL, and then set the validation for all of them.  I take it since this formula references a particular field, I won't be able to do that and instead just copy and paste the formula into the custom validation of each cell?  I.e. there is no "this" construct that allows me to reference the current cell?

Comment: If whole numbers are okay, you can use Method 1. It'll output an error message if the user enters "b.45" or "15.46.78". Basically if the cell you want to validate is C5, use "=ISNUMBER(C5) on the Data Validation dialog box. To apply the validation relatively to other cells, just copy the cell then do Paste Special > Validation. The formula will adjust accordingly.

Comment: The formula for which the validation is based references the current cell.

Answer (score 0):

I think this custom formula meets your needs:

```
=INT(A1)=A1
```